# Kotlin - how to add name to parent `coroutineScope` coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, kotlin-coroutines

It's clear to me that I can name the coroutines when using launch:

```
launch(CoroutineName("test")) { ... }
```

However, I am struggling to get rid of anonymous coroutines showing up on debugger, when the current job is a `coroutineScope`.

```
suspend fun test = coroutineScope { ... }
```

what's the easiest way to add a name to coroutineScope? Currently it's seen as:

`job = "coroutine#1":ScopeCoroutine{Active}@5bf76be8`

Answer (score 1):

I found that the trick is to wrap with `withContext`.

I made a utility to do that:

```kotlin
suspend fun <R> coroutineScopeNamed(name: String? = null, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> R) =
    withContext(name?.let { CoroutineName(name) } ?: coroutineContext) {
        coroutineScope(block)
    }
```

job = "name#1":ScopeCoroutine{Active}@16e7de7d

Another option is to make the class implement CoroutineScope and add

```
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = 
  context + CoroutineName("<name>")
```

however, that doesn't satisfy me because it adds a name on class-level and not on function-level

Another thing to note is that parent names are not kept when adding `CoroutineName`, so the new name should contain all context information needed itself.